# Save Picture in an MS Access 2016 Form Image Control to folder

Tags: vba, forms, image, ms-access

This is my first time posting and before I get into my question I just want to say how much I appreciate all the time and effort everyone puts into solving these problems.

I'm working on setting up a simple project management system which uses both MS Access and Excel.  Through various forms in Access a user can set up a new project with name, address, logo etc. For the logo a user can double click on an image control box and choose a jpeg from any folder they choose.

My problem is with saving the logo. When the user clicks on the Save button, I would like to save the picture into a specific folder, not the one the user choose from.

This code, which works as expected, gives me the file path of where the user chose the picture from and displays the picture.

```
Private Sub CompLogo_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sFile As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Title = "Choose Logo"
   .Filters.Clear
   .Filters.Add "JPEG", "*.jpg"
   If .Show = -1 Then
      sFile = .SelectedItems(1)
   End If
End With

If sFile <> "" Then
    Me.CompLogo.Picture = sFile
End If

End Sub
```

I know I can save the path as text in an Access table...

```
Sub SaveNewProject()    
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ProjectsTbl", dbOpenTable)
        rst.AddNew
        rst!Logo = LogoFilePath
        rst.Update 

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

... but I need the actual jpeg to be saved in the specific folder so it can be used later in the Excel side of the program.

Any help you can give is much appreciated.

Comment: Which step are you struggling with? You can use the `FileCopy` function to copy files to specific folders.

Comment: @ErikA, Sorry it took so long to reply.  I had tried FileCopy in the past but kept getting the error message "70Permission Denied".  Logically, I thought there was a permissions problem with either the folder I was trying to copy from or copy to.  After your post I tried again and discovered that the problem was that the destination was lacking the name of the jpg.  Thanks so much for your reply.